# Keep content from database when updating database.

Tags: database, drupal

I have a website live on the web. I've been working on the re-design for the site. I duplicated the entire site and database and worked on a test site. Now the test site is ready to go live. However, the current live site has been up for the last few weeks and content has been added as usual. How do I upload my new look for the site, with the changes I've made in the test database but at the same time not overwrite any content changes made in the current live database that were made over the past few weeks?

I want to keep the site content in the database but overwrite any module or theme data with the data from the test database. 
My site is built on drupal 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used https://drupal.org/project/data_export_import it seems to be working well.

Answer (score 0):

1) Upload new theme - this will apply themes changes and keep content in the live DB

2) If you have added any new content types, blocks, fields etc to your dev site then install the [features modules](https://drupal.org/project/features). This will allow you to export your new features to a module, and then you can add this module to the live site to import your new features.

See [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2364/how-to-migrate-from-test-environment-to-production-environment) for further discussion on the topic.

Comment: is features much better to use then https://drupal.org/project/data_export_import? I want to update the content on the site.

Comment: For just data use data export. If you need to actually export the content type as well as the content then use features.